# Pasar dos listas consultadas en firebase de diferentes objetos y pasarlas a un controlador que permite la edición y mostrarlas en un lista

Tags: flutter, dart

Vista principal en donde tengo que mostrar en el listView del body la informacion de los Electrodomesticos (el campo de nombre) y Hoja de vida Elect. (campo de ubicacion) como subtitulo del listItem asociados al usuario en sesion, las dos listas le paso la referencia a un controlador que lleva a la vista de editar, pero solo he logrado hacer fucnionar una sola.

```
// ignore_for_file: use_key_in_widget_constructors
    
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:notify_home/controllers/controller_appliance.dart';
    import 'package:notify_home/controllers/controller_login.dart';
    import 'package:notify_home/controllers/controller_register_appliance.dart';
    import 'package:notify_home/controllers/controller_user.dart';
    import 'package:notify_home/models/appliance.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
    import 'package:notify_home/views/calendar_view.dart';
    
    class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
      const HomeView({Key? key});
    
      @override
      State<HomeView> createState() => _HomeViewState();
    }
    
    class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
      final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
      final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
      void _openDrawer() {
        _scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer();
      }
    
      Future<String?> nameUser = getUserName();
      final email = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email;
    
      final user = Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0, bottom: 20),
        width: 100.0,
        height: 100.0,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                image: NetworkImage(
                    "https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.EvZTZb4KMBsXT4RiH5DVpgHaE8?pid=ImgDet&w=474&h=316&rs=1"))),
      );
    
      final signOut = Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        width: double.infinity,
        color: const Color.fromARGB(209, 127, 206, 243),
        child: const Text(
          "Cerrar sesion",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      );
      //Aqui va la  hoja de
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldKey, // Asignamos la clave al Scaffold
          drawer: Drawer(
              child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountName: FutureBuilder<String?>(
                  future: getUserName(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                    } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data == null) {
                      return const Text('Usuario no autenticado o sin nombre.');
                    } else {
                      final userName = snapshot.data;
                      return Text(
                        '$userName',
                        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
                accountEmail: Text(
                  "$email",
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                  child: ClipOval(
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.EvZTZb4KMBsXT4RiH5DVpgHaE8?pid=ImgDet&w=474&h=316&rs=1',
                      width: 90, // Ajusta el ancho según tus necesidades
                      height: 90, // Ajusta la altura según tus necesidades
                      fit: BoxFit
                          .cover, // Ajusta la forma en que la imagen se adapta al círculo
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage(
                            "assets/images/fondo.png"),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover)),
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.calendar_month),
                title: const Text("Calendario de mantenimiento"),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const CalendarNotify()),
                  );
                },
              ),
              Expanded(child: Container()),
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                title: const Text("Cerrar sesion"),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const LoginController()),
                  );
                },
              )
            ],
          )),
          appBar: AppBar(
              leading: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
                onPressed: () {
                  _openDrawer();
                },
              ),
              title: const Text('Mis Equipos')),
          body: ListView(
            children: [
              FutureBuilder<List<Appliance>>(
                future: getApplianceDetails(uid),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return Center(
                      child: Transform.scale(
                        scale: 0.7,
                        child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      ),
                    );
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                  } else {
                    final appliances = snapshot.data;
                    if (appliances != null && appliances.isNotEmpty) {
                      return Column(
                        children: appliances.map((appliance) {
                          return ListTile(
                            leading: const Icon(Icons.devices),
                            title: Text(appliance.name),
                            //subtitle: Text(hve.fabricante),
                            trailing: Row(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                /*IconButton(
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    await Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) =>
                                              ApplianceEditController(
                                                  appliance: appliance, hve: null,)),
                                    );
                                    setState(() {});
                                  },
                                ),*/
                                IconButton(
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    deleteAppliance(appliance);
                                    setState(() {});
                                  },
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return const Text('No se encontraron electrodomésticos.');
                    }
                  }
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              // Agrega la funcionalidad para el botón flotante aquí.
              await Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ApplianceRegisterController()),
              );
              setState(() {});
            },
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
          floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
        );
      }
    }
```

Esta son las funciones que uso para consultar y retornar las listas.
Esta es la Electrodomestico

```
    Future<List<Appliance>> getApplianceDetails(String applianceId) async {
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  try {
    // Realiza la consulta a Firebase Firestore
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await firestore
        .collection('electrodomestico')
        .where('user', isEqualTo: applianceId)
        .get();

    // Inicializa una lista para almacenar los electrodomésticos
    List<Appliance> appliances = [];
    // Recorre los documentos y crea instancias de la clase Appliance
    snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
      appliances.add(Appliance(
        id: doc.id,
        name: doc['name'],
        fabricante: doc['fabricante'],
        modelo: doc['modelo'],
        tipo: doc['tipo'],
        user: doc['user'],
      ));
    });
    // Devuelve la lista de electrodomésticos
    return appliances;
  } catch (e) {
    // Maneja errores de forma adecuada
    print('Error, no se logro obtener la información de los electrodomésticos: $e');
    throw Exception(
        'No se pudo obtener la información de los electrodomésticos.');
  }
}
```

esta es la de Hoja de vida

```
    Future<List<HojaVidaElectrodomestico>> getHVEDetails(String hjeId, String appliance) async {
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  try {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await firestore
        .collection('hojaVidaElectrodomestico')
        .where('user', isEqualTo: hjeId, )
        .get();

    List<HojaVidaElectrodomestico> hojaVE = [];

    snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
      hojaVE.add(HojaVidaElectrodomestico(
        id: doc.id,
        condicionAmbiental: doc['condicionAmbiental'],
        fechaCompra: doc['fechaCompra'],
        fechaInstalacion: doc['fechaInstalacion'],
        fechaMManual: doc['fechaMManual'],
        fechaUltMantenimiento: doc['fechaUltMantenimiento'],
        tiempoUso: doc['tiempoUso'],
        frecuenciaUso: doc['frecuenciaUso'],
        ubicacion: doc['ubicacion'],
        user: doc['user'],
      ));
    });
    return hojaVE;
  } catch (e) {
    throw Exception(
        'Error al obtener la información de los electrodomésticos en la base de datos');
  }
}
```

Quiero mostrar es informacion en el listView y luego pasar al controlador que me lleva a la vista de editar la instancia de los dos objetos.

```
IconButton(
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                          onPressed: () async {
                            await Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) =>
                                      ApplianceEditController(
                                          appliance: appliance, hve: null,)),
                            );
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente ¿Quieres que al ir a la nueva pantalla "ApplianceEditController" o la otra, y que allí se hagan los cambios y se reflejen cuando regreses? No me queda muy claro eso, o ¿Cuál es la falla como tal, o lo que no te funciona bien?

Si quieres tener un estado general, puedes crear unas variables que guarden a las listas de objetos, para que sea más fácil el manejo de los estados, ya que lo ideal cuando se tiene el StatefulWidget, pues es manejarlo así, también puedes usar otros manejadores de estados como bloc, etc.

Cuando me aclares exactamente que es lo que quieres realizar, te puedo orientar mejor, si te sale algún error en consola o algún mensaje, es útil que lo publiques.